# Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). i am trying to deploy in bsc testnet

Tags: solidity, gas-estimate, bsc

i am trying to deploying a contract to bsc testnet but it getting this error :

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message. The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
```

Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }.

here is my code link:
https://github.com/coderbang1/smartcontract/blob/main/code

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor function is using the mainnet PancakeSwap router(on line 621), and because the router address on testnet is different, it fails to create the pair. For testnet, try using the testnet router address, which is `0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1`.

Comment: same problem...

Comment: I got the same error, this change did not help.